# org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter ERROR

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I want to test my application-context.xml if it is well configured or not. So,this is what I did :

```
     public static void main( String[] args )
{

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/context/application-context.xml");
    applicationContext.getBean("entityManagerFactory");
}
```

I got this issue with the entityManagerFactory
I am pretty sure that my dependencies are all compatible and the hibernate-entitymanager is available in my repository.

**My error:**

```
        org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext #prepareRefresh
     INFOS: Refreshing 

      org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3dd6e4a4: startup date [Thu Mar 12 17:02:52 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy              org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/context/application-context.xml]
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource    setDriverClassName
     INFOS: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
     AVERTISSEMENT: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource   [spring/context/application-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#9be2c6f' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#9be2c6f' defined in class path resource [spring/context/application-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine Hibernate PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.app.tn.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#9be2c6f' defined in class path resource [spring/context/application-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine Hibernate PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine Hibernate PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine Hibernate PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManagerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:89)
    ... 26 more

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/context/application-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#9be2c6f' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#9be2c6f' defined in class path resource [spring/context/application-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine Hibernate PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.app.tn.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#9be2c6f' defined in class path resource [spring/context/application-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine Hibernate PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine Hibernate PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine Hibernate PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 21 more
#Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManagerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:89)
    ... 26 more
```

and this is my **application-context** file:

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="       
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd"  default-autowire="byName">

<!-- ========================= CONFIG DEFINITIONS ========================= -->
<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes: Spring's @Required, @Autowired, @Service, @repository, â€¦ -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.tn.*" />
<context:annotation-config />
<task:annotation-driven />

<!-- Entity manager factory declaration -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

    <!-- reference to the datasource -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <!-- Persistence unit manager -->
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />

    <!-- specify Hibernate as the the JPA provider -->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database.ORACLE" />
        </bean>

     </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <entry key="formatSql" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </property>


</bean>   

<!-- Persistence unit declaration -->
<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean> 

<!-- DataSource declaration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
    <property name="username" value="*******" />
    <property name="password" value="*******" />
</bean>

<!-- The transaction manager declaration -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
```

</bean>
    -->

My **pom** file :

```
           <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.app.tn</groupId>
  <artifactId>projet-db</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>app-db</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

<build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- or if you want to use tomcat 6.x <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- http port -->
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${targetJdk}</source>
                    <target>${targetJdk}</target>
                    <encoding>${sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  <dependencies>
        <!-- ORACLE JDBC driver, need install yourself -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>

            <!-- Hibernate c3p0 connection pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

            <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The root cause is:

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManagerFactory**

which should be resolved by your dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Check your local Maven repository for this artifact to see if it has actually been downloaded. Try deleting the folder and running mvn clean install.

On Windows the default location would be:

C:\Users\${user}.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\4.3.8.Final

what is in that folder?

Comment: The dependency is available in my repo, I deleted it and re installed it. but this issue is always remaining.

Comment: My issue was fixed after deleting the hole hibernate folder in my repository and re installing everything all over again! Thank you so much for your help (y)

Comment: Okay, good stuff. I had issues with the 4.3.8 artifact myself last week and had to do the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  These versions of Spring and Hibernate are running OK now for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue ,

I deleted all the dependencies from my repository and then maven again downloaded them fresh and after that it worked fine .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue without using (directly) any hibernate dependencies but Spring Boot. The cause was an outdated version of spring-boot-starter-parent

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
```