# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting following error while running spring application. I am very new to spring so very much stuck here . Need some help to resolve this or tell me how can approach to debug and resolve this issue. I am just going through internet and doing different combinations in my Pom file.

```
14:08:34 [31m[WARN ][0;39m [36m[o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext][0;39m [35m[][0;39m [1;34m[0;39mException encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V
14:08:34 [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m [36m[o.s.boot.SpringApplication][0;39m [35m[][0;39m [1;34m[0;39mApplication startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at hello.springboot.com.HelloApplication.main(HelloApplication.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder$Builder.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6ac27cc9.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$6(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6ac27cc9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a325b6da.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6ac27cc9.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Here is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>hello.springboot.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello.springboot.com</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>

        <!-- Library Versions -->
        <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
        <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
        <cors.filter.version>2.4</cors.filter.version>

        <!-- Plugin Versions -->
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.6.v20151106</jetty.plugin.version>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Jersey Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>${cors.filter.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>hello.springboot.com</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

My applicationContext.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">


    <!-- specify the component scan -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="hello.springboot.com"/>

    <!-- import placeholder values from property files and environment, see default.properties -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/default.properties,classpath*:test.properties"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="hello.springboot.com.repositories" />

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" 
        id="dataSource"> 
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/> 
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:" /> 
        <property name="username" value="sa" /> 
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>   


    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="hello.springboot.com.model" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- take annotation-based configuration into account, when instantiating beans -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
</beans
```

>

Answer (score 8):

Spring `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` includes hibernate by default, so if you are going to use eclipselink it makes sense to exclude hibernate from dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for you 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29016550/5368818)

You forgot the hibernate-entitymanager.jar dependency

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I noticed that the name of database was not correct so it couldn't recognize it.