# Spring data jpa , hibernate and spring mvc compatible versions.

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am using following versions for spring data jpa , hibernate and spring mvc ,

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>`

And I am using following bean configuration for EntityManagerFactory

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpa = new   HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpa.setDatabasePlatform(env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    hibernateJpa.setShowSql(env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql", Boolean.class));

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emf.setPackagesToScan("org.edutool.entity");
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpa);
    emf.setJpaProperties(addProperties());
    emf.setJpaPropertyMap(Collections.singletonMap("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none"));
    return emf;
}
```

But I am facing following error while starting the application

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/edutool/config/JpaConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine Hibernate PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1030)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5348)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine Hibernate PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine Hibernate PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:96)
    at org.edutool.config.JpaConfig.entityManagerFactory(JpaConfig.java:33)
    at org.edutool.config.JpaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1bf7bff5.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$0()
    at org.edutool.config.JpaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1bf7bff5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cb5e2e73.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.edutool.config.JpaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1bf7bff5.entityManagerFactory()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManagerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:89)
    ... 39 more

Nov 22, 2016 9:54:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/himal] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManagerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:89)
    at org.edutool.config.JpaConfig.entityManagerFactory(JpaConfig.java:33)
    at org.edutool.config.JpaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1bf7bff5.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$0()
    at org.edutool.config.JpaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1bf7bff5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cb5e2e73.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.edutool.config.JpaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1bf7bff5.entityManagerFactory()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1030)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5348)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am trying to figure out if the version of the dependencies was the issue or something else. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, have you tried this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015430/org-springframework-orm-jpa-vendor-hibernatejpavendoradapter-error ? Maybe you only have to add a new dependency.

Comment: As hibernate-entitymanager is depricated , the EntityMangerFactory is avaialble on hibernate-core dependency.